# jQuery applying selector on selection using context has strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I use a jQuery selector output which as far as I understand is a jquery object:

```
var myimg=$('img');
```

Now I would like to play with this selection let's say I want to select from the first selection the image that have the string `jpg` in their `src` attribute. This will not work:

```
var myimg3=$("[src*=jpg]",myimg);
```

Actually `$('img',myimg).length` will be 0

Everything seems to behave like in that case jquery would try to select img elements nested in the selected image (See the div element exemple in the jsfiddle below).

What should be the right approach to get the intended behavior?

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/z5e5sog0/2/

Comment: That’s because you are not filtering: you are actually selecting for children in your image element with the src attribute that has “jpg” in it. What you want is to use `.filter()`: ie `myimg.filter('[src*="jpg"]')`

Comment: Yes .filter() will work I have modified the jsfiddle to show this Thanks. But how could I built an object that would encapsulate the selection in such a way that selectors would apply to each selected element not their children ?

Comment: modified jsfiddle showing that .filter() actually works https://jsfiddle.net/z5e5sog0/3/